# Calling the same jquery function on multiple classes and children

Tags: jquery, parallax

OK, so i've hunted for a while and although there are many solutions, I can't quite make them work... am I missing something?

I have 4 separate sections on my page that i want to 'parallax', i want it light as possible and don't want to fiddle with a plugin. So...

My html looks something like this:

```
<section class="pageStripe">
  <div class="parallaxImage" style="background-image:url(/default-header.jpg);">  
    <div class="row">
      <div class="small-12 columns parallaxText">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="small-12 medium-6 columns">
            <div class="parallaxTitle"><h1>Title</h1></div>              
          </div>
          <div class="small-12 medium-6 columns">
            <div class="parallaxContent"><p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p></div>              
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>

<section class="pageStripe">
  <div class="parallaxImage" style="background-image:url(/default-header.jpg);">  
    <div class="row">
      <div class="small-12 columns parallaxText">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="small-12 medium-6 columns">
            <div class="parallaxTitle"><h1>Title</h1></div>              
          </div>
          <div class="small-12 medium-6 columns">
            <div class="parallaxContent"><p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p></div>              
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>

<section class="pageStripe">
  <div class="parallaxImage" style="background-image:url(/default-header.jpg);">  
    <div class="row">
      <div class="small-12 columns parallaxText">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="small-12 medium-6 columns">
            <div class="parallaxTitle"><h1>Title</h1></div>              
          </div>
          <div class="small-12 medium-6 columns">
            <div class="parallaxContent"><p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p></div>              
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

And my jquery something like this:

```
$(window).on('scroll',parallax);
$('.parallaxImage').each(function parallax() {
  var scrolled = $(window).scrollTop() - $(this).offset().top;;
  $(this).css('background-position','center ' + -(scrolled*0.35)+'px');
  $(this).children('.parallaxText').css('top',(scrolled*0.25)+'px');
});
```

All help greatly appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Your giving a name to the closure function your passing into your each().  Either take off the name, or pull the function definition out and pass in just the function name as you are on the .on() call.  Also your doing $(this) three times.  Store it in a variable to reuse for efficiency.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/ay6s50gz/1/

Comment: Perfect, thank you, knew i was missing something.  Shaunak that fiddle really helped. ta